# SQL Syntax Error in my SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone help me figure out what i am doing wrong in my SELECT statement?

```
SELECT *
FROM group
WHERE login = 'admin'
```

My error is:

> right syntax to use near 'group WHERE login = 'admin'' at line 1

It should fail but because of the fact that admin is not in the database but when I plug in data that is in the database it still fails.

Comment: Two quick hints: 1) SQL errors are triggered by MySQL, not PHP 2) Try not to strip the error code when you post the error message here. It provides valuable information as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`GROUP` is a reserved keyword. You need to escape it using back to avoid from syntax error.

```
SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE login = '$username'
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

If you have the privilege to alter the table name, change it to which it is not a reserved keyword to avoid from getting another syntax error again in the future. `:D`

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thank you! It has been awhile since I have worked with SQL so I had forgotten about keywords. I just changed the name of my table and now it works. I will look into the SQL injection stuff also

Answer (score 3):

`GROUP` is a mysql `reserverd keyword` therefore it can be used, place it among backstick

```
`group`
```

Documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)